# Consider 1st row in one to many relation SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, one-to-many

I have two tables one transaction and one master.
The master Table has more than one value for a primary key causing one to many relation and replicating the measures.
Is it possible to capture the actual value of measure at first occurrence and replace the other occurrence of same measure with 0?
This will help me keep the dimensional values but not aggregate the data repetitively.

Transaction table

```
Key  Value
abc  240
def  120
```

Master Table

```
Key  Dimension1 Dimension 2
abc  subcode1   description of abc
abc  subcode2   description of abc
def  subcode1   description of abc
```

Output Required

```
Key  Dimension1 Dimension 2        Value
abc  subcode1   description of abc  240
abc  subcode2   description of abc  0
def  subcode1   description of abc  120
```

Comment: Please show us your effort to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the desired output from the below query

```
SELECT  m.*
    ,(CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.[Key] order by t.[Key]) = 1
        THEN t.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Value
FROM    Master_table as m
    inner join Transaction_table as t   on  t.[Key] =   m.[Key]
```

Here `ROW_NUMBER()` used to identify the first record in that [Key].